# Save JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, mediafire

I'm working with Javascript. I have a JSON response from Mediafire API :

```
{
    "response": {
        "action": "session_token",
        "session_token": "dskldkshjkfsffkjdkslk3783c214a86e7kfkdo",
        "result": "Success"
        "current_api_version": "2.13"
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve the response then save session_token in a variable.

I've tested this but it doesn't work:

Javascript :

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("MY_LINK",function(response){
     var st = response.session_token;
     alert(st);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<button>Get Json</button>
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: why dont you try accessing the json data like this.`var st = response[0].session_token;`

Comment: it's response.response.session_token. Response is the ajax response, response 2 is in your json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your callback function signature, you're receiving a variable named `response`. That is the entire returned object. That object has a property of its own named `response`. You need to access `response.response.session_token` (or edit the returned object to return only what's after `response:` if `response.session_token` is what you want.